# How can I close window in a React Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, keycloak, next.js

This sounds ridiculously simple but I am not be able to find any solution for this from Google.

On my page, I have a button to close the page itself

```
<Button onClick={() => window.close()} >Close</Button>
```

But everytime triggering the button, i got the warning

```
Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.
```

I am using `react-native` for my mobile app, it connects to `keycloak` to (through `WebView` of RN) open Facebook authentication page and then, after that, `keycloak` redirects to `success` page (`localhost/login/success` which has the button to close the page itself. The page is under `next.js`). Even i access `localhost/login/success` directly on browser, I cannot close page neither

**Update** I managed to work around by using `onNavigationStateChange` and check if the `navState.url` contains the `success/login` or not to trigger the state and close the `WebView`. But i am still curious about how to close the window in `React` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`onMessage`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#onmessage) prop to communicate between WebView and React-Native.

> A function that is invoked when the `webview` calls
>   `window.postMessage`. Setting this property will inject a
>   `postMessage` global into your `webview`, but will still call
>   pre-existing values of `postMessage`.

**Example**

```
_onMessage = (message) => {
   console.log(message);
}

render() {
  return (<WebView ref={(ref) => { this.webView = ref; }} onMessage={this._onMessage} ..otherProps />);
}
```

---

```
// In your webview inject this code

<script>
  window.postMessage("Sending data from WebView");
</script>
```

Comment: Thank, this is another way to hack around the solution, though i still want to know how to `window.close` in React Component. +1

Comment: This seems like a hack but actually in react-native removing `WebView` component is equal to `window.close`. So for example opening a `Modal` which contains a `WebView` and then closing `Modal` will give you the same effect as `window.close`.